# Microsoft Bot Framework - Bot doesn't allow messages to be sent

Tags: javascript, c#, botframework

The bot I am making will take in values from the fields and will redirect the user to the appropriate team, sales or support, this is all managed fine in the bot.

The current workflow is: values are entered, the postActivity sends these values, the chat is initiated.

The problem is, the chat interface stops users from entering messages and sending them. Normally when a message is typed, the submit arrow turns blue and the user can then submit. Anyone know why the bot isn't working as intended? Thanks for any guidance.

```
<body>
<div id="hiddenChatFields" style="background-color:white; width:300px;height:600px;">
    Chat Team: <select name="team"><option value="Support">Support</option><option value="Sales">Sales</option></select>
    Name:<input id="name" type="text" />
    Organisation:<input id="organisation" type="text" />
    Email:<input id="email" type="text" />
    Phone:<input id="phone" type="text" />
    <button id="chatSubmit" onclick="initiateChat()">Submit</button>
</div>
<div id="chat" style="background-color:white; width:250px;height:600px;">
    <div id="bot" />
</div>


</body>

<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#hiddenChatFields").show();
    $("#chatButton").show();
    $("#chat").hide();

    const botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
        secret: 'secretHere',
    });

    BotChat.App({
        user: { id: 'You' },
        bot: { id: botid},
        resize: 'detect',
        botConnection: botConnection
    }, document.getElementById("bot"));

    function initiateChat() {
        //todo validation
        $("#chat").show();
        $("#hiddenChatFields").hide();

        botConnection.postActivity({

            type: 'message',

            from: { id: 'You' },

            name: 'buttonClicked',

            value: 'fieldsToPass',

        }).subscribe(function (id) { console.log('Values sent'); });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: After debugging a while, it seems like it is a problem to do with the divs, specifically hiding and showing a div with the bot in. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/515) on Github, it is a known bug at the moment. Proposed solutions are using visibility hidden instead of display none, until it is fixed.